# size of large objects

Tags: r, memory

I need to work with some pretty large data sets. I was wondering if it was better to use a matrix, a list, two vectors or a data.frame. When I calculate the size of small objects (using package pryr) I get different sizes. For example:

```
   library(pryr)
   df <- data.frame(a=rep(10,1000),b=rep(10,1000))
   ma <- matrix(rep(10,2000),1000,2)
   li <- list(a=rep(10,1000),b=rep(10,1000))
   v <- rep(10,1000)
   object_size(df)
   object_size(ma)
   object_size(li)
   object_size(v)*2
```

I get 16.8 kB, 16.2 kB,16.4 kB and 16.1 kB, respectively.

However, when the objects are larger, they seem to be the same size in all cases.

```
   df <- data.frame(a=rep(1211,10000),b=rep(1211,10000))
   ma <- matrix(rep(1211,20000),10000,2)
   li <- list(a=rep(1211,10000),b=rep(1211,10000))
   v <- rep(1211,10000)
   object_size(df)
   object_size(ma)
   object_size(li)
   object_size(v)*2
```

In this case, I get 160 kB in all cases.

I' dlike to know why this is happening. I expected the diference to be more noticeable with larger objects.

Comment: try `compare_size` instead of `object_size` - it reports at they byte level.  What I see is your small df has a size of 16776 and your big df has a size of 160776 - so you have 776 bytes of data.frame overhead and the rest is the data.

Comment: I did as you said. So the difference due to the object class is fixed and it remains small when the data grow. Thank you, I can make a decision now.

Comment: Yup - I would always pick the format the enables the rest of your code to work as efficiently as possible.